# cv2.drawContours why nothing appears?

Tags: python, opencv

Hi I am pretty new to Python and I am trying to obtain bounding rectangles in an image. I did the following:

```
import cv2 
from skimage import io
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('artelab.jpg',0)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)
im2,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
cnt = contours[0]
M = cv2.moments(cnt)
print M
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
cv2.drawContours(img,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
```

Nothing appears but I am not receiving error messages. What's the problem?

Comment: try running the same within a `for` loop so that it identifies all the contours present in the image

Comment: What is the error message? Please paste the whole traceback.

Comment: Perhaps your threshold is being too aggressive. Hard too offer any advise without additional logs/image.

Comment: @JeruLuke thank you, it worked.

Comment: @wfernandez Glad I could be of help :D :D

Answer (score 0):

After adding the for loop, I obtained the bounding boxes around all the objects. Thank you

```
import cv2
from skimage import io
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('paper_artelab.jpg',0)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)
im2,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
numbContours=contours.__len__()

for x in range(0,numbContours):
    cnt = contours[x]
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)
    cv2.drawContours(img,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
io.imshow(img)
```